# What changes to be done for making the plugin work for chrome, as NPAPI support will be stopped by Sept 2015

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, plugins, npapi

Recently after the latest chrome update version 42, NPAPI support was disabled by default in Chrome thus effectively dropping support for Silverlight, Java, Facebook Video and other similar NPAPI based plugins.As per the chromium developer [docs](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation?pli=1) we can temporarily re-enable NPAPI by overriding via 
[chrome://flags/#enable-npapi](http://chrome://flags/#enable-npapi)(Enable NPAPI). However this option will be there only till Sept 2015.They have also mentioned that this wait is for mission-critical plugins to make transition.

[image]

We are using an enterprise plugin and we have some dependency on chrome , to make the transition we have to re-implement the plugin.
***What are the things we need to do for re-implementing*** and ***make it work for chrome***, guys please shade some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what exactly your plugin needs to do; FireBreath 2 is nearly ready and supports plugins in Chrome via native messaging, however:

- For Chrome you must install an extension as well as installing the binary (the binary installer can trigger the extension install, but must be confirmed by the user)
- There is no direct drawing model, so you'd need to use a javascript layer to draw and access it from the plugin
- All APIs of FireBreath 2 plugins are now asynchronous.
- FireBreath 2 is not quite ready, though you're welcome to help us get it ready.

Other options include Native Client, which has much better drawing support but is sandboxed, and Emscripten which allows you to compile C++ to javascript and is shockingly fast, but is also of course sandboxed.  You could also write your own native messaging host to do what you need.

As @smorgan says, there is no one solution that is a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general-purpose replacement that can do everything NPAPI plugins could do, so without knowing what your plugin does there's no way to answer that question.

You should look at the last section of the [deprecation guide](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation), and see if your plugin fits into one of the categories there. If not, you should post a specific question about what you want to accomplish.